# Adding the website as an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a website deeloped in ASP.NET and I want it to be accessed via local URL, for eg: http://localhost/website20

I tried once but the CMS in my website started giving error "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."
Please help about the steps I need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a virtual directory for your site, either in VS project properties or in IIS, depending on type of VS project template you are using.

Comment: umm.. could you please elaborate on how to create this virtual directory? For the project templates, I started from an ASP.NET empty website.

Comment: You can create a virtual directory for a website but normally it is run with the built-in server. My advice would be to use the Web Application project template. Then just right-click the folder in IIS7 to create the virtual directory, or use Project Properties in VS :-)

Answer (score 0):

Steps maybe a bit different depending on which Win ver and IIS ver you have, but you have to go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> IIS -> then on the default website hit right click and do "Create Virtual Directory".